# How can upload image URL in SQL server and retrieve in grid view using ASP.NET?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008

How to upload image URL in SQL server and retrieve in grid view using ASP.NET?

Can you point me to any tutorials and/or sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consult [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Answer (score 1):

- [Gridviews with Pictures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx)
- [Using SQL](http://www.cs.swan.ac.uk/~csneal/ReliableWeb/Example.html)

That one's not so hard! = )

In addition to your gridview, I'd suggest using a TextBox to enter your URL data(s).

Comment: Thanks! And welcome to StackOverflow! Let us know if you have any more programming questions.